# elastic search regex query to search string starts with number

Tags: elasticsearch

i am not able to search string start with number

```
PUT music/song/1?refresh
{
    "suggest" : [
        {
            "input": "123hello",
            "weight" : 3
        }
    ]
}
```

i have tried the following regex query

```
POST music/_search?pretty
{
    "suggest": {
        "song-suggest" : {
            "regex" : "^[0-9].*$",
            "completion" : {
                "field" : "suggest"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of ES are you using?  Have you reviewed the docs for suggesters (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html) and regexp queries (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html)?

Comment: 5.5 elastic search  version i am using

Answer (score 0):

You should try `[0-9]*.*`.

The point is that lucene regexp doesn't use `'^'` and `'$'` as symbols of start and end of the string to anchor your pattern. In fact regexp in lucene is anchored to whole string by default, [see](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#_standard_operators):

> Most regular expression engines allow you to match any part of a string. If you want the regexp pattern to start at the beginning of the string or finish at the end of the string, then you have to anchor it specifically, using ^ to indicate the beginning or $ to indicate the end.
>
> Lucene’s patterns are always anchored. The pattern provided must match the entire string.

See also my very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50717706/regexp-starts-with-not-working-elasticsearch-6/50733071#50733071). Especially if your field could be more then 256 characters.

Don't know if question is still actual, so I just leave it here.

Comment: Surely `[0-9]+.*`  as the operator `*` means Repeat the preceding character zero or more times. So it will match any string. While `[0-9]+.*` will match a string that starts with number?