# Regexp starts with not working Elasticsearch 6.*

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, lucene

I got trouble with understanding regexp mechanizm in ElasticSearch. I have documents that represent property units:

```
{
    "Unit" :
    {
         "DailyAvailablity" : 
         "UIAOUUUUUUUIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOUUUUIAAAAOUUUIAOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOUUUUUUUUUUIAAAAAOUUUUUUUUUUUUUIAAAAOUUUUUUUUUUUUUIAAAAAAAAOUUUUUUIAAAAAAAAAOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUIUUUUUUUUIUUUUUUUUUUUUUUIAAAOUUUUUUUUUUUUUIUUUUIAOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUIAAAAAAAAAAAAOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
    }
}
```

DailyAvailability field codes availability of property by days for the next two years from today. 'A' means available, 'U' unabailable, 'I' can check in, 'O' can check out. How can I write regexp filter to get all units that are available in particular dates?

I tried to find the 'A' substring with particular length and offset in DailyAvailability field. For example to find units that would be available for 7 days in 7 days from today:

```
{
 "query": {
   "bool": {
     "filter": [
        {
         "regexp": { "Unit.DailyAvailability": {"value": ".{7}a{7}.*" } }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This query returns for instance unit with DateAvailability that starts from "UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUIAA", but contains suitable sequences somehere inside the field. How can I anchor regexp for entire source string? ES docs say that lucene regex should be anchored by default.

P.S. I have tried `'^.{7}a{7}.*$'`. Returns empty set.

Comment: Regexps are not case insensitive. Try `"[^A]*A{7}.*"`

Comment: ES ignores case, I suppose. I tried to use uppercase. It returns empty set everytime.

Comment: What happens when you use: `{ "query": { "regexp":{ "Unit.DailyAvailability": ".{7}A{7}.*" }}}`

Comment: Uppercase symbols lead to empty results. `'.{7}a{7}.*'` returns all units with suitable sequences inside. I suspect that issue is somehow connected with anchoring of regexp in lucene. Another possibility: ES can not parse large string properly.

Comment: How are you analyzing that field? Your analysis is the reason that you need to search with lowercase, and is probably responsible for this behavior as well. [ngrams](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html), perhaps?

Comment: I don't use any special analysis, so it is standart, I suppose. What analysis do you advice me in this case?

Comment: Aside from the uppercase thing, did you test what would happen if you excluded the "bool" and "filter" contexts like in my example? (using the lowercase "a")? It may be easier to troubleshoot your regex if you remove as many other potential points of failure as possible.

Comment: @Marathon55, thanks, I will try it!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you are using [`text`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/text.html) datatype to store `Unit.DailyAvailability` (which is also the default one for strings if you are using [dynamic mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/dynamic-field-mapping.html)). You should consider using [`keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/keyword.html) datatype instead.

Let me explain in a bit more detail.

#### Why does my regex match something in the middle of a `text` field?

What happens with `text` datatype is that the data gets analyzed for full-text search. It does some transformations like lowercasing and splitting into tokens.

Let's try to use the [Analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/indices-analyze.html) against your input:

```
POST _analyze
{
  "text": "UIAOUUUUUUUIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOUUUUIAAAAOUUUIAOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOUUUUUUUUUUIAAAAAOUUUUUUUUUUUUUIAAAAOUUUUUUUUUUUUUIAAAAAAAAOUUUUUUIAAAAAAAAAOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUIUUUUUUUUIUUUUUUUUUUUUUUIAAAOUUUUUUUUUUUUUIUUUUIAOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUIAAAAAAAAAAAAOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
}
```

The response is:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "uiaouuuuuuuiaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaouuuuiaaaaouuuiaouuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuiaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaouuuuuuuuuuiaaaaaouuuuuuuuuuuuuiaaaaouuuuuuuuuuuuuiaaaaaaaaouuuuuuiaaaaaaaaaouuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuiuuuuuuuuiuuuuuuuuuuuuuuiaaaouuuuuuuuuuuuuiuuuuiaouuuuuuuuuuuuuuu",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 255,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "uuuuuuuuuuuuuuiaaaaaaaaaaaaouuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuiaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
      "start_offset": 255,
      "end_offset": 510,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaouuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuiaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
      "start_offset": 510,
      "end_offset": 732,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, Elasticsearch has split your input into three tokens and lowercased them. This looks unexpected, but if you think that it actually tries to facilitate search for words in human language, it makes sense - there are no such long words.

That's why now `regexp` query `".{7}a{7}.*"` will match: there is a token that actually starts with a lot of `a`'s, which is an [expected behavior](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html) of `regexp` query.

> ...Elasticsearch will apply the regexp to the terms produced by the
> tokenizer for that field, and not to the original text of the field.

#### How can I make `regexp` query consider the entire string?

It is very simple: do not apply analyzers. The type [`keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/keyword.html) stores the string you provide as is.

With a mapping like this:

```
PUT my_regexes
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "Unit": {
          "properties": {
            "DailyAvailablity": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You will be able to do a query like this that will match the document from the post:

```
POST my_regexes/doc/_search
{
 "query": {
   "bool": {
     "filter": [
        {
         "regexp": { "Unit.DailyAvailablity": "UIAOUUUUUUUIA.*"  }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the query became case-sensitive because the field is not analyzed.

This `regexp` won't return any results anymore: `".{12}a{7}.*"`

This will: `".{12}A{7}.*"`

#### So what about anchoring?

The regexes are [anchored](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#_standard_operators):

> Lucene’s patterns are always anchored. The pattern provided must match the entire string.

The reason why it looked like the anchoring was wrong was most likely because tokens got split in an analyzed `text` field.

Comment: **VERY** nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just in addition to brilliant and helpfull answer of Nikolay Vasiliev. In my case I was forced to go farther to make it work on NEST .net. I added attribute mapping to `DailyAvailability`:

```
[Keyword(Name = "DailyAvailability")]
public string DailyAvailability { get; set; }
```

The filter still didn't work and I got mapping:

```
 "DailyAvailability":"type":"text",
     "fields":{  
         "keyword":{  
             "type":"keyword",
             "ignore_above":256
         }
      }
 }
```

**My field contained about 732 symbols so it was ignored by index**. I tried:

```
[Keyword(Name = "DailyAvailability", IgnoreAbove = 1024)]
public string DailyAvailability { get; set; }
```

It didn't make any difference on mapping. And only after adding manual mappings it started working properly:

```
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
client.CreateIndex("vrp", c => c
    .Mappings(ms => ms.Map<Unit>(m => m
        .Properties(ps => ps
            .Keyword(k => k.Name(u => u.DailyAvailability).IgnoreAbove(1024))
        )
     )
  ));
```

The point is [that](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/keyword.html):

> ignore_above - Do not index any string longer than this value. Defaults to 2147483647 so that all values would be accepted. Please however note that default dynamic mapping rules create a sub keyword field that overrides this default by setting ignore_above: 256.

So use explicit mapping for long keyword fields to set `ignore_above` if you need to filter them with regexp.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone could be useful, the ES tool does not support the \d \w modes, you should write those as [0-9] and [a-z]