# Kibana using regex doesn't work as expected

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, kibana-6

I'm quite new to the use of Kibana and Elastic search, but I have it working and can search on strings etc no problem.

But I want to search on this regex

```
threshold of 1000 ms: ([5-9],\d+|[1-9][0-9],\d+|[1-9][0-9][0-9],\d+)
```

Which works as tested using https://regex101.com/ and using Notepad++.
But I cannot get it to function in Kibana no matter what I try.

I've tried changing the indexed field to keyword instead of text but still doesn't work.

Even a simple regex like

```
message:/192.168.99.[0-9]{3}/
```

Doesn't work as you would expect.

Can someone suggest a way to get this to work please?  It's driving me nuts.

I should mention I am using Filebeat 6.4.2, Elasticsearch 6.4.2 and Kibana 6.4.2

Thanks

MAPPING

```
"mappings": {
  "doc": {
    "date_detection": false,
    "properties": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "@version": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "CorrelationId": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 1024
      },
      "InteractionNumber": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 1024
      },
      "RequestorId": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 1024
      },
      "alertType": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 1024
      },
      "app": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 1024
      },
      "beat": {
        "properties": {
          "hostname": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 1024
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 1024
          },
          "version": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 1024
          }
        }
      },
      "host": {
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 1024
          }
        }
      },
      "input": {
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 1024
          }
        }
      },
      "level": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 1024
      },
      "logger_name": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 1024
      },
      "message": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "nodeId": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 1024
      },
      "offset": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "pegathread": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 1024
      },
      "prospector": {
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 1024
          }
        }
      },
      "source": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 1024
      },
      "source_host": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 1024
      },
      "src-env": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 1024
      },
      "src-node": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 1024
      },
      "src-vm": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 1024
      },
      "stack": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 1024
      },
      "tenantid": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 1024
      },
      "thread_name": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 1024
      },
      "userid": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 1024
      },
      "x-requested-with": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 1024
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example message field content

```
2018-10-20 23:10:21,068 GMT*8*PEGA0001*8087*1000*8ce767fc2b32*NA*NA*HKVZWM7PHSLMGR3ZXP4OEKEBG3DFFS30K*Test.User*Case-CAS-FS-Work-Svc*Solution:01.03.01*00cb8b6febb234d359369e54a60a865f*Y*3*HKVZWM7PHSLMGR3ZXP4OEKEBG3DFFS30K*35*http-apr-8080-exec-26*STANDARD*com.pega.pegarules.session.internal.engineinterface.service.HttpAPI*192.168.99.100|192.168.99.1*Activity=Pega-UI-CommandPalette.pzGetPaletteOptions*Rule-Obj-Activity:pzGetPaletteOptions*PEGA-UI-COMMANDPALETTE PZGETPALETTEOPTIONS #20161123T194957.445 GMT Step: 2 Circum: 0*NA*****pxRDBIOElapsed=0.03;pxRDBIOCount=4;pxRunStreamCount=811;pxTotalReqCPU=2.81;pxRunModelCount=270;pxOutputBytes=584,268;pxRunWhenCount=1,904;pxDeclarativePageLoadElapsed=6.84;pxRulesExecuted=3,471;pxOtherCount=314;pxDBInputBytes=3,553,909;pxTotalReqTime=8.09;pxActivityCount=967;pxAlertCount=1;pxOtherFromCacheCount=66;pxInteractions=1;pxLegacyRuleAPIUsedCount=1;pxRuleCount=254;pxInputBytes=101;pxRuleIOElapsed=0.09;pxRulesUsed=4,262;pxDeclarativePageLoadCount=6;pxRuleFromCacheCount=254;pxOtherIOElapsed=0.99;pxTrackedPropertyChangesCount=106;pxOtherIOCount=255;*NA*NA*NA*NA*NA*pyActivity=Pega-UI-CommandPalette.pzGetPaletteOptions;primaryPageClass=Data-Portal-DesignerStudio;*HTTP interaction has exceeded the elapsed time alert threshold of 1000 ms: 8088 ms.*
```

Added message type as string and this is the _analyze results :-

```
{
  "token": "threshold",
  "start_offset": 1276,
  "end_offset": 1285,
  "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
  "position": 128
},
{
  "token": "of",
  "start_offset": 1286,
  "end_offset": 1288,
  "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
  "position": 129
},
{
  "token": "1000",
  "start_offset": 1289,
  "end_offset": 1293,
  "type": "<NUM>",
  "position": 130
},
{
  "token": "ms",
  "start_offset": 1294,
  "end_offset": 1296,
  "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
  "position": 131
},
{
  "token": "8088",
  "start_offset": 1298,
  "end_offset": 1302,
  "type": "<NUM>",
  "position": 132
},
{
  "token": "ms",
  "start_offset": 1303,
  "end_offset": 1305,
  "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
  "position": 133
}
```

Comment: How does the mapping for your index look like ? Are you fields analyzed or not_analyzed ? See https://www.timroes.de/2016/05/29/elasticsearch-kibana-queries-in-depth-tutorial/

Comment: I'm unsure how to check if they are analysed or not.

Comment: Check your index mapping

Comment: Mapping altered, but makes no difference.

Comment: Please post your index mapping

Comment: Index mapping is in my post.  This was exported from filebeat and then altered to suit.

Comment: OK. Your mapping shows message field as keyword so it is not analyzed.. Your simple regex above will work if message field only contains IP address that matches the regex pattern. What does your message field contain ? Only IP address or a string which includes an IP address ?

Comment: Ignore the IP address one for now, that was an example.  My message field contains all sorts of things but the example I am looking at I've update my post with.

Comment: Ok your mapping says ‘message’ field type is keyword i.e. it is not analyzed by Elasticsearch and the whole field content is put into inverted index as is. Ideally your message field mapping type should be text so Elasticsearch analyzes it using standard analyzer (unless you specify an explicit custom analyzer) and puts tokens into the inverted index and is searchable using regex patterns. Unfortunately, you cannot change the mapping type of an existing field in an index. You should create a new index with correct mapping and reindex your data.

Comment: I had the field as text originally and it doesn't work.  I've recreated this index so many times with different variations, nothing appears to work as I would expect.  So from the documentation :-
_"The regexp query allows you to use regular expression term queries. See Regular expression syntax for details of the supported regular expression language. The "term queries" in that first sentence means that Elasticsearch will apply the regexp to the terms produced by the tokenizer for that field, and not to the original text of the field."_

Comment: Does this mean that regex only applies to individual tokens and not combination of tokens?  I've updated my post after changing the message type back to text and added the _analyze results.

Comment: So the problem with having message as string is that only words are split out, therefore I can't search for non word patterns such as commas.  I found this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50717706/regexp-starts-with-not-working-elasticsearch-6] and thought it would solve my issue, but alas it simply doesn't work.  I can't be the only one with this requirement.

Comment: Hi, did some testing. Will add my observations in the below answer as its elaborate

Answer (score 2):

Tested on version 6.2.4

Added the below index with mapping as shown below

```
    PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "message": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "message2": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Added 2 documents to the index as below

```
PUT test/_doc/1?refresh
{
  "message": "hellothere",
  "message2":"2018-10-20 23:10:21,068 GMT*8*PEGA0001*8087*1000*8ce767fc2b32*NA*NA*HKVZWM7PHSLMGR3ZXP4OEKEBG3DFFS30K*Test.User*Case-CAS-FS-Work-Svc*Solution:01.03.01*00cb8b6febb234d359369e54a60a865f*Y*3*HKVZWM7PHSLMGR3ZXP4OEKEBG3DFFS30K*35*http-apr-8080-exec-26*STANDARD*com.pega.pegarules.session.internal.engineinterface.service.HttpAPI*192.168.99.100|192.168.99.1*Activity=Pega-UI-CommandPalette.pzGetPaletteOptions*Rule-Obj-Activity:pzGetPaletteOptions*PEGA-UI-COMMANDPALETTE PZGETPALETTEOPTIONS #20161123T194957.445 GMT Step: 2 Circum: 0*NA*****pxRDBIOElapsed=0.03;pxRDBIOCount=4;pxRunStreamCount=811;pxTotalReqCPU=2.81;pxRunModelCount=270;pxOutputBytes=584,268;pxRunWhenCount=1,904;pxDeclarativePageLoadElapsed=6.84;pxRulesExecuted=3,471;pxOtherCount=314;pxDBInputBytes=3,553,909;pxTotalReqTime=8.09;pxActivityCount=967;pxAlertCount=1;pxOtherFromCacheCount=66;pxInteractions=1;pxLegacyRuleAPIUsedCount=1;pxRuleCount=254;pxInputBytes=101;pxRuleIOElapsed=0.09;pxRulesUsed=4,262;pxDeclarativePageLoadCount=6;pxRuleFromCacheCount=254;pxOtherIOElapsed=0.99;pxTrackedPropertyChangesCount=106;pxOtherIOCount=255;*NA*NA*NA*NA*NA*pyActivity=Pega-UI-CommandPalette.pzGetPaletteOptions;primaryPageClass=Data-Portal-DesignerStudio;*HTTP interaction has exceeded the elapsed time alert threshold of 1000 ms: 8088 ms.*" 
} 


PUT test/_doc/2?refresh
{
  "message": "2018-10-20 23:10:21,068 GMT*8*PEGA0001*8087*1000*8ce767fc2b32*NA*NA*HKVZWM7PHSLMGR3ZXP4OEKEBG3DFFS30K*Test.User*Case-CAS-FS-Work-Svc*Solution:01.03.01*00cb8b6febb234d359369e54a60a865f*Y*3*HKVZWM7PHSLMGR3ZXP4OEKEBG3DFFS30K*35*http-apr-8080-exec-26*STANDARD*com.pega.pegarules.session.internal.engineinterface.service.HttpAPI*192.168.99.100|192.168.99.1*Activity=Pega-UI-CommandPalette.pzGetPaletteOptions*Rule-Obj-Activity:pzGetPaletteOptions*PEGA-UI-COMMANDPALETTE PZGETPALETTEOPTIONS #20161123T194957.445 GMT Step: 2 Circum: 0*NA*****pxRDBIOElapsed=0.03;pxRDBIOCount=4;pxRunStreamCount=811;pxTotalReqCPU=2.81;pxRunModelCount=270;pxOutputBytes=584,268;pxRunWhenCount=1,904;pxDeclarativePageLoadElapsed=6.84;pxRulesExecuted=3,471;pxOtherCount=314;pxDBInputBytes=3,553,909;pxTotalReqTime=8.09;pxActivityCount=967;pxAlertCount=1;pxOtherFromCacheCount=66;pxInteractions=1;pxLegacyRuleAPIUsedCount=1;pxRuleCount=254;pxInputBytes=101;pxRuleIOElapsed=0.09;pxRulesUsed=4,262;pxDeclarativePageLoadCount=6;pxRuleFromCacheCount=254;pxOtherIOElapsed=0.99;pxTrackedPropertyChangesCount=106;pxOtherIOCount=255;*NA*NA*NA*NA*NA*pyActivity=Pega-UI-CommandPalette.pzGetPaletteOptions;primaryPageClass=Data-Portal-DesignerStudio;*HTTP interaction has exceeded the elapsed time alert threshold of 1000 ms: 8088 ms.*",
  "message2":"hellothere" 
}
```

Search for `message2: /192.168.99.[0-9]{3}/` results in 0 results

Search for `message: /192.168.99.[0-9]{3}/` results in doc#2

Search for `message2: /.*192.168.99.[0-9]{3}.*/` results in doc#1

Search for `message: /pegarules.session/` results in 0 results.

But search for `message: /.*pegarules.session.*/` results in doc#1
because inverted index has `"token": "com.pega.pegarules.session.internal.engineinterface.service.httpapi"`

Search for `message2: /.*pegarules.session.*/` results in doc#1`

So, the message filed (type `text`) is tokenized and regex search for wild card token patterns is returning results.

Where as, the message2 field (type `keyword`) is not analyzed and is put in to the inverted index as is. Regex search for a pattern like `192.168.99.[0-9]{3}` is not returning anything unless we add greedy quantifier (.*)

The Lucene regular expression engine is not Perl-compatible but supports a smaller range of operators so it may not work and match results like regular regex.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#regexp-syntax

Comment: Thanks for that but it didn't work for me when I tried it.
Search for message2: /192.168.99.[0-9]{3}/ results in 0 results **--correct**
Search for message: /192.168.99.[0-9]{3}/ results in doc#2 **--correct but doesn't highlight what was requested simply highlights 0 and 3!**
Search for message2: /.*192.168.99.[0-9]{3}.*/ results in doc#1 **--incorrect returns nothing**
Search for message: /pegarules.session/ results in 0 results. **--correct**

Comment: But search for message: /.*pegarules.session.*/ results in doc#1 because inverted index has "token": "com.pega.pegarules.session.internal.engineinterface.service.httpapi"
**--incorrect returns nothing**
Search for message2: /.*pegarules.session.*/ results in doc#1` **--incorrect returns nothing**

Comment: I am not sure if the behavior is different due to diff versions of ES but will test it later and report.